# How do I rotate gridlines of a parametric surface in Geogebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, parametrization

[image]I was trying to visualise Lorentz transformations and parametrized a surface by using the matrix $A$ below, with $-k$ as rapidity.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\cosh(k) & \sinh(k) \\ 
\sinh(k) & \cosh(k)
\end{bmatrix}$$

I took the product $$A \times  R$$ (rotation matrix) to rotate gridlines, but this is just applying the Lorentz transform to a rotated surface and thus the geometry got distorted. The product $R \times A$ just rotates the Lorentz transformed square so that didn't help.

Is there a way to preserve the shape and just rotate gridlines? Like a parametric square using the identity matrix but then rotating the gridlines in it without moving it around.

I also tried using a polar parametrisation but couldn’t find the explicit polar equation of a square and I also don’t know if this will work. Is there another method I can use, I think being limited to active linear transformations in geogebra (plz correct me if I'm wrong here) is causing this when I need a passive transform or maybe even something else entirely (like polar parametrisation I guess?)

Thanks for the help.

edit: Added the pics, here I set the rotation as pi/4 and zero and then multiplied by A (k=-1) so I get gridlines parallel to eigenvectors and the comoving frames respectively. I wanted to see a the same gridlines as in image one but with the outline as in grid 2.

Comment: What do you by "surface" here ? Do you mean something in 3D or do you work in 2D ?

Comment: Lorentz boosts are squeeze transforms so they will distort shapes.

Comment: $\|A\cdot x\| \ne \|x\|$

Comment: I’m working in 2d

Comment: Hey Cesareo, I see that the vectors will be stretched but if we take the spacetime metric that will make their proper time equal (not for lightlike). Does not using a the minkowski metric and hence the stretching here make it difficult to rotate gridlines? I am adding a few images too.